# Waterproofing Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

the project i'm working on is a weather station out door and for that i need to to give arduino at least some sort of protection from moisture.

https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Weather-Station-AWS/

putting arduino in a box might work but the humidity where i live is very high it's rain a lot but the cold is not much. looking for ideas to waterproof arduino board please.

also can arduino work everyday of year without problem?

Comment: Google "Conformal Coating" and "Epoxy Potting Compound".

Comment: Using a waterproof enclosure? Just make sure the heat doesn't get too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just solder everything you need to the Arduino (I would recommend using an Arduino Mini since it has no communication port) and coat it with Silicon Conformal Coating. It creates a silicon layer on top of the PCB that would not let any moisture through. Or you can just put it in a case and cover it with epoxy, that will be even more protection, but there will be no more access to the board unless you foresee it.